# Why is this spring security configuration blocks all paths?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

```
public class AuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

SecureService secureService;

public AuthenticationFilter(SecureService secureService) {
    this.secureService=secureService;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest=(HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
    Authentication authentication=secureService.getAuthentication(httpServletRequest);
    if(authentication!=null) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }
}

}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
SecureService secureService;
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(secureService), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/businesses/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/reviews/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/reviews/search").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/reviews/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll().and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

what's wrong with this configuration? I followed with this [link](http://technicalrex.com/2015/02/20/stateless-authentication-with-spring-security-and-jwt/) to write url authentications. But my app keeps blocking all requests, ignoring all the matchers specified in the code. I googled and someone said the order of rules matters. But even though I change the order, `AuthenticationFilter` **gets invoked all the time and keeps blocking all requests**.

Comment: That is what you told it to do, the last line overrides the ones before...

Comment: @M.Deinum That's not true. The filters are read one after the other. So if NONE of these filters before matched any other will need authentication.

Comment: Just to be sure.. You have annotated your configuration with @Configuration?

Comment: @YannicKlem yes, I've updated my code

Comment: @M.Deinum I remove the last line, the `AuthenticationFilter` gets called for every request.

Comment: Is your project available on github, so i can clone it to have a deeper look at it?

Comment: @YannicKlem ok. this is the link https://github.com/RyanZhu1024/boot-security.git  . Now it's working because I create a custom map to do url filtering. I left the `antMatchers` unchanged. You can comment the map I created and see if the `antMathcers` is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93423/discussion-between-yannic-klem-and-ryan-zhu).

Comment: Is the propblem solved?

Comment: The ant matchers should not be /users instead of /users/?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you interrupt the filter chain. do it as the following and it should work.

```
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        Authentication authentication = secureService.getAuthentication(httpServletRequest);
        if (authentication != null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }
```

Another thing is that you throw a UserNotFoundException inside your SecureService if the HttpServlerRequest does not contain an Authentication.
In the AuthenticationFilter you seem to expect null in this case? So return null in the SecureService if no Authentication exists:

```
public Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    final String token=httpServletRequest.getHeader(Headers.AUTH_HEADER_NAME);
    if(token!=null){
        final User user=parseToken(token);
        if(user!=null){
            return new UserAuthentication(user);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

if you want to keep the UserNotFoundException then only change the doFilterMethod to the following:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

    try {
        Authentication authentication = secureService.getAuthentication(httpServletRequest);
        if (authentication != null) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
    }catch(UserNotFoundException e){
    }finally {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: I add the `AuthenticationFilter` class. I use this custom filter is because I want to use JWT token authentication rather than session control.

Comment: I tried this solution. still not working. the exception is thrown in the `getAuthentication(httpServletRequest)` method, because it's getting called from those unnecessary urls where token does not need to be provided, which leads to a UserNotFoundException thrown in the method

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. I just changed the doFilter method of your code and everything works. When sending get request to 'http://localhost:8080/businesses/' the answer is '{"data":[],"msg":null}' when sending get request to 'http://localhost:8080/users/1' i get an 403 response unless i don't get a valid token from your login endpoint (works for me, too). You may push your current version, so i can have a look at differences

Comment: https://github.com/RyanZhu1024/boot-security/blob/master/src/main/java/org/usf/cs601/filters/AuthenticationFilter.java   here is my updated filter same as yours. not working. I feel so bad..

Comment: Oh no .. sorry. It was my fault. Another problem was that you throw UserNotFoundException in your SecureService if no Authentication exists. Return null if no authentication exists (as you seem to expect it in your AuthenticationFilter) and it will work. Sorry.. was late yesterday and i forgot that i changed this. If you want to keep this exception than change the way you handle it in the AuthenticationFilter to a try-catch and don't forget to keep the filterChain alive in the catch block ;)

Comment: Actually, my first assumption is when I configure the antMatchers on those urls, the method `doFilter` in the `AuthenticationFilter` will be be called when the paths are not in the antMatchers. But the fact is it gets called all the time, like the antMatchers doesn't exist. I mean, for example, if the request path is root path `/`, then the `AuthenticationFilter` won't get called. it should just ignore this filter rather invoking `doFilter` method and let the authentication process being handled with try-catch or null handling.

Comment: I want the `AuthenticationFilter` being used for only those paths not registered as `permitAll()` in the configuration class

Comment: okay .. i'll give up. I fixed your bug and the authenticationFilter works as it should. If the your application still doesn't work like you want it, please have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/